# How to assign events to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign events to variables, because I can't delete `$('body').on('keyup')` event with different callbacks (sorry for my English). It is impossible?

```
function test_1()
{
    $('body').on('keyup', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 1
    }
}

function test_2()
{
    $('body').on('keyup', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 2
    }
}
test_1();
test_2();
```

And now I want to delete the event listener who executes 'do stuff 2' on keypress.

I want to something like that:

```
var handler_1;
var handler_2;
function test_1()
{
    handler_1 = $('body').on('keyup', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 1
    }
}

function test_2()
{
    handler_2 = $('body').on('keyup', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 2
    }
}
function delete()
{
   handler_2.off();
}
test_1();
test_2();
```

And then I execute delete() I want that handler_2 will turn off the event. But when I press any key the 'do stuff 1' must be work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use name-spaced events. This allows you to assign a name to the event so that you can easily remove it later. Also, when you assign the result to `handler_1`, you are actually just getting back a jquery object representing the body element, so it would be equivalent to `$('body')`, so I don't think it's necessary.

```
function test_1()
{
   $('body').on('keyup.fn1', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 1
    }
}

function test_2()
{
    $('body').on('keyup.fn2', function(e)
    {
        //do stuff 2
    }
}
function delete()
{
   $('body').off('keyup.fn2');
}
test_1();
test_2();
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
function keyup1(e)
{
    //do stuff 1
}
function test_1()
{
    $('body').on('keyup', keyup1);
}
function delete()
{
    $('body').off('keyup', keyup1);
}
```

See the first example in the [documentation page for `off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Take a look at Brian's answer; I think it might be closer to what you want (since you can define the handlers anonymously, inside a function, and remove them by name rather than keeping them in a variable).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `bind` so for example:

```
var e1 = function () { ... },
    e2 = function () { ... };

$('#target').bind('keyup', e1);
$('#target').bind('keyup', e2);
$('#target').unbind('keyup', e1);
$('#target').unbind('keyup', e2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `on / off`

```
function handler1() {
    alert("I will fire!");
}

function handler2() {
    alert("I won't fire!");
}

$(document).on('keyup', handler1);

$(document).on('keyup', handler2);

$(document).off('keyup', handler2);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz759/)